# positioning html img tag in as3 via xml/cdata

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, xml-parsing, cdata

I've been trying to position an image tag in actionScript3 (from an xml file) like this:

```
<![CDATA[

Hey, <br/>
<img style="margin-left:200px;" src="imgs/_mamo.jpeg"/>
<p>

some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
</p>
<p>
Thanks,<br/>
web-dev.
</p>
    ]]>
```

but as3 is not using the styling.

Is AS3 able to recognize css styling? If not how would I position the image tag?

Comment: AS3 does not have the ability to parse HTML (beyond HTML 1), and cannot parse CSS at all. AIR, however, can parse and style HTML with CSS. However, for case this small, you could just use plain ActionScript to write out text and load and position an image.

Comment: +1 yeah the Adobe docs (at lease the ones i've read) don't seem to come out and just say they don't support css (it's seems like there's vague hints), but anyway, I figured i'd have to go the as3 image object rout (i have no problems with that way). just wanted to make sure I wasn't trying to "place a nail with a jackhammer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest (if you aren't married to pure ActionScript for your project) that you check ou the following link...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff2.html

Flex has the ability to use style sheets for both components as well as text using the wonderful CSS you are used to.

Flex for AIR also provides a container for rendering above HTML 1. FlashBuilder's proprietary MXML can also give you more freedom in mixing images with text.

Comment: this is a good answer so I'll accept it. unfortunately I didn't create this project (that person's long gone) and since they don't have the time for me to refactor this it will have to be married to as3 at the moment. for now I'll have to use as3's image object and just load/append that way, but it is good to know flex and mxml are options down the road.

Comment: One other thing you might check out is the possibility of using the TextLayoutFramework (TLF) for ActionScript 3. It works for both Flex and pure AS3 projects and affords a huge amount of freedom over the previous Text Engine. Check it out here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/tlf.html